# Input type email doesn't work on mobile

Tags: android, iphone, email, input

I have an input type "email", that works on website, but doesn't work in mobile - neither in Android or Iphone. Doesn't even show the keyboard.

Comment: Can you post some code for us?

Answer (score 0):

if you want to enter email address inside edittext you must set edittext input type like this.

```
android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
```

hope it help you.